# Hdd not showing while installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive, live-usb, boot-partition

Currently I am using POP OS.
I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my ACER laptop, but my 1GB HDD and partitions are not showing.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: PopOS isn't supported here.  Is your computer's hard drive in RAID / Intel RST mode in your BIOS?

Comment: I want to change my OS. Popos to ubuntu. And here I am getting issue.

Comment: I asked you a question in my last comment, can you answer it?